# Order of result changes when making an AJAX request in a loop

Tags: jquery, loops, asynchronous

I have a loop which contains `$(selector).append(myhtmlblock)` but my blocks are not displayed in the correct order.

How can I display the elements in the same order as my object's data?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('groupes_modules')) {
    var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('groupes_modules'));
    data = Object.values(data);
    $(data).each(function(key, values) {
      $.get("inc/form/groupes_modules_module.php", {
        nmodule: key
      }, function(ungroupe) {
        $("#collapsiblegroupes").append(ungroupe); //My append

      })
    });
  };
```

Comment: Is there any way you can get all the data you need from *one* AJAX call instead of many calls in a loop?

Comment: No, I do not think so

Comment: In that case you would need to aggregate all the responses to the AJAX requests and manually `sort()` them.

Comment: You could `.append()` during the `.each()` loop (maybe with a hidden element or with a loading indicator) then in the callback the html element will already exist and you can update with `.html()`.

Comment: Bear in mind if you send all your ajax requests at the same time, you might overload the php server (especially with a lot of values).  You could implement an ajax queue to wait for one before kicking off the next.